# Java get filename of download from redirected 'friendly' url

Tags: java, redirect, download, url-routing, nio

I'm trying to download a file from a given URL which may or may not be a direct link to the file. Does anyone know how I can detect the filename to write to if the URL is an indirect link (i.e http://www.example.com/download.php?getFile=1) ? 
It is no problem if the URL is a direct link to extract the filename from the URL and start writing to the extracted filename but with a redirect link the only method I have found so far is to write to an arbitrary filename  - foo.txt - and then try and work with that. Problem is I really need the filename (and extension) to be correct. 
A sample of the code I am using is: (the section in the 'else' clause is neither finished nor working):

```
public static boolean dlFile(String URL, String dest){
    try{
        URL grab = new URL(URL);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(grab.openStream());
        String fnRE = ".*/([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\._]+)$";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(fnRE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);
        String fName = "";
        if(matcher.find()) fName = matcher.group(1);
        else { //filename cannot be extracted - do something here - below doesn't work raises MalformedURLExcpetion
            URL foo = new URL(URL);
            HttpURLConnection fooConnection = (HttpURLConnection) foo.openConnection();
            URL secondFoo = new URL(fooConnection.getHeaderField("Location"));
            System.out.println("Redirect URL: "+secondFoo);
            fooConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            URLConnection fooURL = secondFoo.openConnection();
        }
        System.out.println("Connection to "+URL+" established!");
        if(dest.endsWith("/")){}
        else dest+="/";
        System.out.println("Writing "+fName+" to "+dest);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest+fName);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

I am sure there must be a simple way to get the filename from the headers or something like that but I cannot work out how to get it. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not in general, though if the response has a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.zip` header you could extract the filename from that.

Comment: @IanRoberts - yes I thought this but unfortunately there is no Content-Disposition header being returned, all the headers I can get by following the URL are just telling me its php/html etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the response has a "Location" header field, I was able to obtain the direct link to a url *containing multiple redirects* like this:

```
String location = "http://www.example.com/download.php?getFile=1";
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
for (;;) {
    URL url = new URL(location);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    String redirectLocation = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
    if (redirectLocation == null) break;
    location = redirectLocation;
}
//and finally:
String fileName = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, location.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use Java [Jsoup](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.13.1) library, then use the below method:

```
public static void downloadFileJsoup(String URL, String PATH) throws IOException {
    Response res = Jsoup.connect(URL)
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .timeout(30000)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .maxBodySize(20000000)//Increase value if download is more than 20MB
            .execute(); 
    String remoteFilename=res.header("Content-Disposition").replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"?([^\"]+)\"?.*$", "$1");
    String filename = PATH + remoteFilename;
    FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(filename)));
    out.write( res.bodyAsBytes());
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in general no way. The response does'nt contain that information normally, since you do not add any own protocol information to the data stream (in case you can control the server).

Anyway, you ask for the file name extension. Maybe with the correct [content-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type) you are done.

Comment: is there no way to download a file without knowing a filename to write to then? is there no way of saying 'download to default filename' or something to that extent? this seems insane as it is easily doable in other languages but I need this work in java . boo :-(

Comment: No, that is HTTP works and has nothing to do with Java. If the server don't give you that information (Content-Disposition) you can maybe read in the bytes into a buffer. Some file formats contains the own original file name (specially open formats).

Comment: Hi yes you a right. I just looked at a python script I'd wrote to do the same thing and that only works by reading the Content-Disposition from the header. I assume when I connect the the url with urllib2 it must be following the redirect before returning me the headers as it gives completely different headers to what I can get from java. I'm sure I have read you can set a property to force redirection to be followed but I can't seem to make it work. Hmmmmmmm.

Comment: @psf In the absence of a `Content-Disposition` header, browsers and tools like wget simply guess the file name to use from the last path segment of the URL.